What are the 270 mitzvot relevant today?
It says in this post
that, by some calculation, it was figured that 270 Mitzvot are observable today. Does anyone have a list of these 270 Mitzvot?

The Chofetz Chaim wrote a sefer (Sefer Hamitzvos Hakatzar) listing all of the commandments applicable today. He lists 77 positive commandments and 194 negative commandments, for a total of 271.

The linked post discusses a tradition of 270 mitzvot from the Shelah (and the Chinuch) comprising 48 positive and 222 negative. Does the Chafetz Chaim discuss how and why his calculation differs from this?

Thanks for the answer. I am curious though how this is reconciled with the Shelah as mentioned above

@CuriousYid that's a separate question. B'chavod, ask it!

@JoelK It's two completely different sets of criteria. The Chofetz Chaim's list is the mitzvos that apply today. The Chinuch lists the mitzvos that apply to everyone even without any prerequisites, but those don't necessarily apply today (aliyah l'regel, korban pesach). The Chinuch would not count paying a worker on time (because you have to hire one first), but the Chofetz Chaim does. The Shelah says there are 369 mitzvot that apply today, without listing them. THe author of the linked post implies these two numbers are connected, but they are not.

@N.T. I don’t think that’s right. The Chinuch writes that there are 369 mitzvot applicable today, of which 270 apply without conditions. So paying a worker on time is not in his 270 (but it is in his 369), but Korban pesach is also not in the 270 (nor the 369). יש מצות הנוהגות בזמן הזה, והם בין כלם שלש מאות ששים ותשעה. ויש מאלו הנוהגות שלא יתחיב בהן האדם כי אם בסבה, ופעמים שלא תבא הסבה לו לאדם בכל ימיו ונמצא שלא יעשה אותה לעולם ... והם בין כלם תשעה ותשעים, מהן שמנה ושבעים עשה ואחד ועשרים לא תעשה. אבל אותם מצות שחיבין בהם כל אדם מישראל מבלי שיתחדש בו סבה בעולם, הם בין כלם מאתים ושבעים

@JoelK In that case, all I can say is the Chofetz Chaim does not explain. The Chinuch also does not explain his list. Originally he put marks next to the ones that were in the 270 and 369, but those have been lost. See the Machon Yerushalayim edition of Minchas Chinuch.

R Hutner (Pachad Yitzchaq RH pg 48) gives the mnemonic "אֲנִ֥י יְשֵׁנָ֖ה וְלִבִּ֣י עֵ֑ר … - I am asleep but my heart is awake." ער (awake) is 270 in gematria. Paused in learning it to share here.
